# How to get hold of image data from webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter

I'm using [jsOauth-twitter](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth-Twitter) to upload an image to twitter which calls the [update_with_media api method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media). It looks like it needs the actual image data. This is already on my webpage inside a normal `<img src="localfile">` tag.

Using Javascript, can I get at the actual image data (JPEG) to pass it to the function? Is it available in the DOM? I need the raw image data so I can pass it to twitter as application/octet-stream, so base64 is no good to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image data in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Comment: I've added more to the question, which is why that possible duplicate won't meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API requires the form to be sent as multipart/form-data, which means the media[] parameter is expecting a file rather than binary or base64 encoded data. If you use HTML file input inside a form, this should be fairly straightward.

If you must use the <img> tag, then it would be difficult. All I can think of is draw the image to a <canvas>, obtain a base64-encoded URI with `toDataURI()`, decode it to obtain the raw image data using [window.atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob), then build the multipart/form-data POST body manually. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript/934925#934925) has some sample code for the first couple of things.

The `Blob` API may help in creating a file-like object which your OAuth library can accept (rather than manually building the request body), but its not very well supported yet.

Comment: You might want to check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/341353

Comment: I don't have to use the image tag, I just thought that might be easy as the browser has already loaded it. Putting the img tag in a form is no problem. How do I refer to the image tag in that case? It's not an input or other form field.

Comment: Yes that does the first step of obtaining the base64 data, but not decoding or posting it to Twitter which is the OPs objective.

Comment: @paul If its not loaded via an <input> then you'll have to use the method as described above / by the link from abitgone.

Comment: I need the file in application/octet-stream (Twitter requirement) not base64.

Comment: One you have retrieved the base64-encoded data via the canvas `toDataURI()` method, you can then use the `atob()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob (or use a library) to decode it and access the raw binary data.

Comment: @Graham I've edited the answer to include that. I could have used a library, but native code should be quicker hopefully.